# Is it OK to rename Flyway repeatable migrations?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I have set up a bunch of repeatable migrations for my project to drop (and recreate) some frequently modified database views. The package structure looks something like this:

```
src/main/resources
  |-db
    |-R__pets_amphibians_view.sql
    |-R__pets_birds_view.sql
    |-R__pets_mammals_view.sql
    |-R__pets_reptiles_view.sql
    |-...
    |-<versioned-migrations>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to split the `R__pets_mammals_view.sql` view up into two more specific views: *e.g.* `R__pets_mammals_dogs_view.sql` and `R_pets_mammals_rodents_view.sql`, respectively. This would also entail renaming/deleting the original `R_pets_mammals_view.sql` file.

What I would like to know is whether I can do this without messing up my schema versioning (possibly killing any hosted environments in the process)? Unfortunately, I could not find an answer to this in the Flyway docs.

*P.S.:* I understand that it's not a good idea to rename versioned migrations once they've been deployed to anything beyond the local environment. However, since repeatable migrations can be modified at will (and since they're executed last), I'm not sure whether they actually "count" in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a technical point of view, you can add, remove and rename repeatable migrations as you like. Flyway will not do anything with removed repeatable migrations. These migrations will also remain in the `schema_version` table. So you can still track which repeatable migrations were executed on your schema even if they have been removed.

In your example, where you delete the `R__pets_mammals_view.sql` and add two other views, the "mammals" view will just remain on your schema and you might drop it via a versioned migration (or manually).

Comment: As of flyway 9.8.1, this is not correct. Flyway will complain about missing scripts for repeatable migrations and refuse to perform the migration.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, maybe this behaviour can be configured (see https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/ignoreMigrationPatterns).